# Django template not found - tried different locations

Tags: django, django-templates

I am really confused.  I have a django site with the below structure:

```
demo
|-demo
   │-settings.py
   │-urls.py
   │-templates
   │-__init__.py
|-manage.py
|-public
   |-templates
|-db.sqlite3
|-app
   |-templates
|-stderr.log
```

I have created a templates directory at the top level, within apps and within public and none of the templates get picked up and I get the **Template does not exist at** error.

My settings looks like this - i've tried adding loads of different options when it comes to the template path (including leaving it empty) but none have worked.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'demo',
    'app',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'demo.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['/usr/local/lsws/Example/html/demo/app/templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

My login view is:

```
def login_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = request.POST.get('username').lower()
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=user, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('index')
        else:
            messages.success(request, ('Login failed'))
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        return render(request, 'login.html', {})
```

Can anyone help me?!

Comment: `I have created a templates directory at the top level` - which one out of shown folders? I don't see any `templates` folder here.

Comment: I've tried under /demo and also under /app and under /public :) - i've updated above

Comment: And where is login.html located? Please show full structure and describe which app is your template supposed to belong to.

Comment: I added login.html under all 3 because I couldn't understand why it's not working. The app they belong to is simply called app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to modify your **TEMPLATES** *`'DIRS'`* like this

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ....
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        ....
    }
]
```